# TypeError: __init__() takes 4 positional arguments but 7 were given

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance

```
class Employee(object):
    def __init__(self,ename,salary,dateOfJoining):
        self.ename=ename
        self.salary=salary
        self.dateOfJoining=dateOfJoining
    def output(self):
        print("Ename: ",self.ename,"\nSalary: ",self.salary,"\nDate Of 
Joining: ",self.dateOfJoining)
class Qualification(object):
    def __init__(self,university,degree,passingYear):
        self.university=university
        self.degree=degree
        self.passingYear=passingYear
    def qoutput(self):
        print("Passed out fom University:",self.university,"\nDegree:",self.degree,"\Passout year: ",self.passingYear)
class Scientist(Employee,Qualification):
    def __int__(self,ename,salary,dateOfJoining,university,degree,passingYear):
        Employee.__init__(self,ename,salary,dateOfJoining)
        Qualification.__init__(self,university,degree,passingYear)
    def soutput(self):
        Employee.output()
        Qualification.output()
a=Scientist('Ayush',20000,'21-04-2010','MIT','B.Tech','31-3-2008')
a.soutput()
```

I'm not able to get a solution to the problem and I'm not able to understand why this TpyeError has occured. I'm new to python. Thanks

Comment: For which class the error occurent ? Can you give us the full exception trace?

Comment: For Scientist Class

Comment: Post the python traceback that shows the line where the error occurred.

Comment: @tdelaney Here you goTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/84.py", line 22, in <module>
    a=Scientist('Ayush',20000,'21-04-2010','MIT','B.Tech','31-3-2008')
TypeError: __init__() takes 4 positional arguments but 7 were given

Comment: Scientist init take 6 param you give 6. Their not problem here. Post the full trace plz.

Comment: You have a typo in `__init__`. You wrote `__int__`. Its using the dunder init of the parent class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your scientist class has the init function written as :

```
def __int__
```

instead of

```
def __init__
```

So what happened is it inherited the init function from its parent class, which receives less params then you sent to the class.

Also instead of calling the init of the parents you should be using the super function.

```
super(PARENT_CLASS_NAME, self).__init__()
```

This obviously goes for all parent functions.

Answer (score 1):

Your Scientist class constructor is misspelled as `__int__` instead of `__init__`. Since there is no overridden constructor to be used from the Scientist class, it goes up a level on the inheritance chain and uses the Employee's constructor, which in fact only uses 4 positional arguments. Just fix the typo and it should work.

(there are a few other bad things you're doing with classes in your code, but I'll allow other people to comment with tips)